# OKTA Authentication in Offline mode

Tags: ios, react-native, okta

I have a react native ios app in which authentication is done using OKTA. As of now authentication of user is done by redirecting the user to OKTA login page and after  authenticated in OKTA  the user will come back into ios app. But my app should work in offline mode also how to authenticate a user using OKTA in OFFLINE mode. Can any one tell me how to validate the user when he is not connected to internet.

should i make use of any OKTA Primary authentication by making a custom login page.

Comment: You can't use OAuth authentication when then authenticating party (ie Okta) is unreachable.  You could fall back to some sort of local authentication such as a PIN code if you are offline.

Comment: Yeah. but can i make a custom login page and make user enter login details and store the password into my DB and send a request to the OKTA with username and password to authenticate. for example i got to know about primary authentication by browsing URL(https://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/authn#primary-authentication-with-public-application)

Comment: You could do that I guess. As long as Okta supports the client credentials grant type. You would store the password in the keychain, not your database